# Using $this when not in object context php - how to fix?

Tags: php

I have a private var:

```
$test;
```

I want access inside a function:

```
private function whatever(){

     function getTest(){
        var_dump($this->test);
     }
}
```

I get the error:

```
Using $this when not in object context php
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You are using $this inside simple function not in object. Why do you create getTest function insinde another function?

Comment: You are not inside of the object. You have to use a parameter for `getTest` for this

Comment: This is an abstracted example, I cannot change the getTest method as this is part of something else.

Comment: Can't you extract the getTest method to a normal function in this class?

Comment: `getTest` is not a "method" to begin with, because it's not attached to a class. What you're doing there with `function getTest` is you **declare** a new global function; this may not work at all the way you think it does. You *will* have to clarify the purpose of this.

Comment: Could you show us the class (or at least a bit more of it) and how you're instantiating it?

Comment: This question contains too little context. There is enough to tell what the problem is, but since you deny each suggestion because of unshown things that you apparently can't change, it's just a guess if a correct answer will ever be found. Please provide context on how the method and the function are used, and which part you can't change.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an object of the instance in this way. Just use `getTest` as a normal method of your class object:

```
private function whatever(){
    $this->getTest();

}

function getTest(){
    var_dump($this->test);
}
```

Comment: Cant move the method out of whatever method

Comment: @panthro It (`getTest`) is not a "method". It's a plain global function. Why can't you move it out?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an object as an instance in that way, instead use it as a normal method of your class eg

```
 class MyClass {
    private function whateverFunction(){
        $this->getTestFunction();

    }

   public function getTestFunction(){
        var_dump($this->test);
    }
  }
```